# Do I need to finish a mission to receive its challenge unlock?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

Do I need to complete a mission after completing 2 challenges to receive the mission unlock? Does replaying a mission, having completed it without 2 challenges before, change anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting a challenge to register requires you to complete the mission.
Thus, getting a challenge reward to unlock requires you to complete the mission.

You can replay a mission and still have the reward unlock.